# cvtColor in openCV creating array of stretched images?

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, native

I'm using the android native sample activity. When I use the cvtcolor function, my output is four copies of my input shrunken and without color. Without the cvtcolor function the input is perfect, except of course, it has color.

To be more specific, the output is four columns. The output is grey. If it were filming a face, the face would be stretched downward and look super long.

```
       cvtcolor(input, output, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

Given my limited image processing knowledge i have no idea where to begin or what to do next. I am on a Moto X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android images are 4 channel. Therefore you need something like

```
cv::Mat gray;
cv::cvtColor(input, gray , CV_BGRA2GRAY);  // convert 4 channel color to 1 channel gray
cv::cvtColor(gray , output, CV_GRAY2BGRA); // convert 1 channel gray to 4 channel gray
```